# Program in Stata that differentiates file type (datasets and do-files)

Tags: if-statement, dataset, stata

I am trying to write a simple program in Stata where my students can download datasets and example do files from my website. This program is called "usecda" and below is the example where it only opens datasets.

```
capture     program drop usecda
program     define usecda
args        data 
use         https://tamaravdd.github.io/icpsrcda/`data', clear
end
```

Then I can do:

```
usecda hrs_subset.dta
```

I would like the same program to run do-files. How I differentiate the do-files from dataset file in the program (using an if-statement I assume)? I am open to either differentiate them by file type (.dta or .do) or by using a term in the name file (the do-files all have "lecture" in them).

This program would be able to do the `usecda hrs_subset.dta` to open the dataset and also `usecda cda_lecture_nominal.do` to run the do file

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Subversively, or otherwise, why not just tell them that stuff is at https://tamaravdd.github.io/icpsrcda so that they can type `use` to read in named datasets? Or `do` for named do-files? `use` and `do` are commands that are key in any case; why add your own commands to the learning burden when they are just wrappers?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! This is for a very introductory class so I would like to have them dealing with my github website only once and then have an easy command to download everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something for you to work off of:

```
capture program drop usecda
program define usecda
    args data

    // check for .dta file
    if substr("`data'",length("`data'")-3,4) == ".dta" {

        //use "https://tamaravdd.github.io/icpsrcda/`data'", clear
        di "dta file"

    }

    // check for .do file
    else if substr("`data'",length("`data'")-2,3) == ".do" {

        //do "https://tamaravdd.github.io/icpsrcda/`data'"
        di "do file"

    }

    // throw error if not .dta or .do
    else {

        di as err "File `data' incorrectly specified"

    }
end


usecda asdf.dta

usecda asdf.do

usecda asdf.doc
```

the idea is to check the file extension and if it is a .dta file then do something, if it is a .do file do something else, and if it is not either of those then throw an error to the user.

I included examples of each under the program definition.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had tried the substr command before but did not know how to make it work with a dataset name instead of a string variable. This is very useful.